# Div Container will not adhere to margin, padding, or gap

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and web development in general. My experience is in Python. I am having issues with  containers contained in a grid view not adhering to any margin, padding, or gap I add on the right or the left. It does fine with the top and bottom but everything I have tried hasn't worked for right and left.

```css
/* CSS style for my container.*/ 

.results-container {
  text-align       : left;
  background-color : var(--container-color);
  /* Background color of the container */
  color            : var(--text-color);
  border-radius    : 5px;  /* Rounded corners */
  padding          : 10px;       /* Spacing inside the container */
  max-width        : 100%;
  width            : 100%;
  box-shadow       : 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Add a shadow for visual effect */
  display          : flex;
  flex-direction   : column;
  margin           : 10px;
}


/* The style for the Grid View. */

.grid-container {
  display               : grid;
  grid-template-columns : repeat(3, 1fr); /* Automatically decide the number of columns based on screen width */
  margin                : 20px;
  gap                   : 20px;
  justify-items         : center;
  align-items           : center;
  padding               : 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="results-container">
    <h4 class="song-name">Testing Container</h4>
    <p class="song-info">Author: Casey Koehn</p>
    <p class="song-info">First Verse: Test verse here</p>
    <p class="song-info">Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="results-container">
    <h4 class="song-name">Testing Container</h4>
    <p class="song-info">Author: Casey Koehn</p>
    <p class="song-info">First Verse: Test verse here</p>
    <p class="song-info">Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="results-container">
    <h4 class="song-name">Testing Container</h4>
    <p class="song-info">Author: Casey Koehn</p>
    <p class="song-info">First Verse: Test verse here</p>
    <p class="song-info">Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="results-container">
    <h4 class="song-name">Testing Container</h4>
    <p class="song-info">Author: Casey Koehn</p>
    <p class="song-info">First Verse: Test verse here</p>
    <p class="song-info">Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="results-container">
    <h4 class="song-name">Testing Container</h4>
    <p class="song-info">Author: Casey Koehn</p>
    <p class="song-info">First Verse: Test verse here</p>
    <p class="song-info">Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inspector Screenshot
[image]

Problem Screenshot
[image]

I have tried adding margin to the containers, padding to the grid view, gap to the grid view, and tried removing the box shadow all to no avail. As previously mentioned, I am new to web dev and am still learning. It may be a very simple error that I am not catching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invest some time to learn the [CSS box model](https://web.dev/learn/css/box-model/).

[image]

By default, the width/height of an element refers to the width/height of the **content box**; it does **not** include the padding box or the border box. So, if you set `width: 100%;` on an element, and that element has padding, then its apparent size will be larger than 100%.

The easiest solution is just to remove `width: 100%;` on your grid children. They will behave perfectly well without further instructions.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}

.grid-container>* {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(0 0 0 /0.7);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.grid-container>*>* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another possible solution would be to set `box-sizing: border-box;` on the grid children. This rule means that any width/height you specify should **include** the padding and border, instead of exclude it.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}

.grid-container>* {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(0 0 0 /0.7);
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.grid-container>*>* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Testing Container</h4>
        <p>Author: Casey Koehn</p>
        <p>First Verse: Test verse here</p>
        <p>Chorus: Test chorus here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have time for futher reading, [these](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) [articles](https://css-tricks.com/international-box-sizing-awareness-day/) describe some of the history of the box model, and why we have the `box-sizing` option for switching between the two competing models.

Comment: I am using the width 100% because I want my container to be as big as possible in the grid. But the box-sizing option was exactly what I needed! Thanks for the answer and the articles.

Comment: I understand, but I think you'll find it will do that anyway, without you telling it specifically. If you run my first snippet (in which I deleted the `width: 100%`) and view it full page, you'll see that the grid children do stretch horizontally to fill the columns.